# Getting content offset of List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, list, offset, swiftui

I'm trying to create a parallax header effect in SwiftUI like this one https://twitter.com/KhaosT/status/1140814602017464320 , but don't really know how to get content offset of the list while scrolling.

Does anyone have know how to calculate the content offset of the list while scrolling?

Comment: On a reply on that tweet, the author suggests to use a `GeometryReader` to get it. Did you test that approach?

Comment: yes, I manage to use `GeometryReader` to get content offset from a `ScrollView`, still investigating how to apply the same technique to `List`. Source code for `ScrollView` is here: https://github.com/peacemoon/SwiftUIParallaxHeader/blob/master/SwiftUIParallaxHeader/ContentViewScrollView.swift

Comment: Still looking for a solution for List.  Anyone found anything (I'm using Beta3 and still no love, as far as I can find).

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729619/what-is-geometry-reader-in-swiftui

Comment: @Peacemoon I guest your gist answers the original question. Shouldn't you answer and accept is as correct? Or a full solution is required?

Answer (score 7):

I provided a reusable solution for the `ScrollView` case on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58416243/8653910) which makes use of **View Preferences** as a method to notify layout information upstream in the View Hierarchy.

For a  detail explanation of how **View Preferences** work, I will suggest reading this [3 articles series](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/) on the topic by [kontiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7786555/kontiki)

Unfortunately, such solution does not work for `List` (perhaps a bug) as the *View Preferences* get trapped inside the `List` and are not visible by its ancestors.

The only feasible solution so far is to observe the frame changes on the views inside the list. You could achieve this in two ways:

You can report and listen to layout changes on every view (cell) on the list (and act on it):

```swift
struct TestView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List(TestEnum.allCases) { listValue in
                Text(listValue.id)
                    .padding(60)
                    .transformAnchorPreference(key: MyKey.self, value: .bounds) {
                        $0.append(MyFrame(id: listValue.id, frame: geometry[$1]))
                    }
                    .onPreferenceChange(MyKey.self) {
                        print($0)
                        // Handle content frame changes here
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or, alternatively, report and listen to frame changes on some table header view (or an empty header) if you do not need the frame changes on every cell:

```swift
struct TestView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List {
                Text("")
                    .transformAnchorPreference(key: MyKey.self, value: .bounds) {
                        $0.append(MyFrame(id: "tableTopCell", frame: geometry[$1]))
                    }
                    .onPreferenceChange(MyKey.self) {
                        print($0)
                        // Handle top view frame changes here. 
                        // This only gets reported as long as this 
                        // top view is part of the content. This could be
                        // removed when not visible by the List internals.
                    }

                ForEach(TestEnum.allCases) {
                    Text($0.rawValue)
                        .padding(60)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Find below the supporting code for the solutions above: `PreferenceKey` conforming struct, an identifiable view frame struct and a test enum as data source:

```swift
struct MyFrame : Equatable {
    let id : String
    let frame : CGRect

    static func == (lhs: MyFrame, rhs: MyFrame) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.frame == rhs.frame
    }
}

struct MyKey : PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [MyFrame] // The list of view frame changes in a View tree.

    static var defaultValue: [MyFrame] = []

    /// When traversing the view tree, Swift UI will use this function to collect all view frame changes.
    static func reduce(value: inout [MyFrame], nextValue: () -> [MyFrame]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

enum TestEnum : String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten

    var id: String {
        rawValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Text ("") left offset above

Comment: How can i know if a List is on Top or is scrolled? Get like a boolean answer.