# What is Geometry Reader in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI. And I come across to "GeometryReader". And I want to know why and when to use it?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

### UPDATE

***Since I posted the answer, I have also written an article on how GeometryReader works. Check it out for a more detailed explanation: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/***

---

GeometryReader is a view that gives you access to the size and position of its parent. For example:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
           // Here goes your view content,
           // and you can use the geometry variable
           // which contains geometry.size of the parent
           // You also have function to get the bounds
           // of the parent: geometry.frame(in: .global)
        }
    }
}
```

I usually combine it with .background() to obtain some other view's bounds. For example, The Text view is hard to predict how large it would be in advance. When I need that information, I use this trick:

First I have defined a view called GeometryGetter:

```swift
struct GeometryGetter: View {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect
    
    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.makeView(geometry: geometry)
        }
    }
    
    func makeView(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        }

        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Then, to get the bounds of a Text view (or any other view):

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var rect: CGRect = CGRect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("some text").background(GeometryGetter($rect))

        // You can then use rect in other places of your view:
        Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: rect.height)
    }
}
```

For some use cases, I posted some answers to other questions that use GeometryReader. Check them out:

Move textfields to avoid being hidden by the keyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56721268/7786555

How to make view the size of another view in SwiftUI:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56661706/7786555

**Note**

In GeometryGetter, I added a DispatchQueue.main.async {} to set the rect. In some cases it could lead to runtime warning otherwise: *Modifying state during view update*.

Comment: Updated the answer to include some use cases.

Comment: Since I posted the answer, I added a link to an article I have written about GeometryReader. It expands the answer further. Cheers.

Comment: Can you help us here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243677/proportional-height-or-width-in-swiftui to understand why the GeometryReader in the accepted answer needs the layoutPriority modifier in order to get the result? Thx.

Comment: That geometry getter is very useful. Thank you for posting.

Comment: Very useful way of using Geometry reader, but i think calling frame(in:) asynchronously isn't a good idea for dynamic content (view inside list for instance), this will lead to crash, a workaround would be to fetch the frame synchronously and then dispatch it asynchrounouly

Comment: @Aleyam, do you have some sample code and if so, are you willing to create it as an answer?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting crashes on `self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)` when changing tabs. Apparently, removing the Async call makes it work again.

Comment: This technique might end up in endless loop depending on how you use the `rect` value. It was discussed in the WWDC 22 session "Compose custom layouts with SwiftUI" at 18:20 mark https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/

Answer (score 3):

#### What is called `Reader` in SwiftUI?

In addition to the kontiki's answer, `Reader`s are container views that define their content as a function. So they can have some access and abilities about their `parent`. They are generic structs if you look more closely and there is 2 readers available now in SwiftUI 2.0:

<sub>Note that it's just a convention, they're not conforming special protocol more of the `View` protocl</sub>.

## GeometryReader

```
struct GeometryReader<Content: View> : View
```

This is A container view that defines its content as a function of its own size and coordinate space. So you can detect frame and position changes and the current state of any view within a `GeometryReader`. One of the popular usage of this reader that when you need separate views in separate stacks have the same (or relative) sizes.

---

## ScrollViewReader

```
struct ScrollViewReader<Content: View> : View
```

This is view whose child is defined as a function of a `ScrollViewProxy` targeting the scrollable views within the child. So you can have some access to the scrollview like **[scrolling to a specific item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623787/5623035)** or similar stuff.

<sub>To minimalizing the duplication, I didn't post examples, you can check the link for more information if you want</sub>

Answer (score 0):

GeometryReader is thing that recognize geometry of parents view means when you create a view in the geometry you get size of your parent view.