# How to access parents frame in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, inheritance, constraints, width, swiftui

Still working on SwiftUI, but I got a problem.
I created an Image with a dynamic frame, and I want a label which needs to be half width of the image (e.g Image width = 300; Label width 150)

In UIKit I should code something like this:

```
Label.widthAnchor.constraint(image.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive = true
```

I tried something similar in SwiftUI:

```
Image(systemName: "j.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        Text("Placeholder").frame(width: Image.frame.width/2, height: 30)
```

But this doesn't work.

What shall I do?

Comment: Geometry Reader is a possible solution. Take a look into this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729619/what-is-geometry-reader-in-swiftui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not setting hard sizes for both then :

```swift
Image(systemName: "j.circle.fill")
     .resizable()
     .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

Text("Placeholder")
     .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: 30)
```

If you want to change the whole size of the component in one place you could just do it like this :

```swift
struct MyView : View {

     private var compWidth: CGFloat { UIScreen.main.bounds.width }

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             Image(systemName: "j.circle.fill")
                   .resizable()
                   .frame(width: compWidth, height: compWidth)

             Text("Placeholder")
                   .frame(width: compWidth/2, height: 30)
         }
     }
}
```

Or, for a more elegant approach you could [look into](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) `GeometryReader`.

Comment: In the second code I should put between the {   } the dimension that I want?

Comment: @Vipera74: Yes, you could even compute it with "regular" swift code.

Comment: Cool, let me know if it worked (by accepting my answer :-)

Comment: Btw, the `private var ...` part should be put outside the `body` of the view.

Comment: "Attribute 'private' can only be used in a non-local scope" I get this error and a couple more errors

Comment: Oh you wrote while I was writing

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tick your answer