# Xcode 11 beta 4 - relativeWidth is deprecated

Tags: swiftui

I have a `VStack` nested inside of an `HStack` that I want to take up 35% of the safe area width. So far through beta 3 I've been able to do the by:

```
HStack {
    VStack {
        .
        .
        .
    }.relativeWidth(0.70)
}
```

But I now have a warning that:

> 'relativeWidth' is deprecated

That's it. Nothing about what to use as a replacement. In fact, the documentation hasn't yet marked it as deprecated.

Any ideas on what I can use as an alternative? `GeometryReader`? It seems that that is overkill. (I know, `relativeWidth` still works, but I prefer removing all warnings if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is deprecated. The [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_4_release_notes) say:

> The relativeWidth(*:), relativeHeight(*:), and
>   relativeSize(width:height:) modifiers are deprecated. Use other
>   modifiers like
>   frame(minWidth:idealWidth:maxWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxHeight:alignment:)
>   instead. (51494692).

Your only alternative seems to be GeometryReader :-(

Comment: Yes, I do not understand why they put that there. But in beta 3, they did the same with many other notes. I don't get it.