# Overlay with relative Width

Tags: swiftui

Xcode 11 Beta 4 deprecated `.relativeSize` as well as `.relativeWidth` and `.relativeHeight` (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57095182/xcode-11-beta-4-relativewidth-is-deprecated)).

So what is the alternative?

I want to create an overlay that has a width relative to it's parent.

Let's say I have the following main view

```
struct MainView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        BackgroundView()
        SideBarView()
          .frame(idealWidth: 200)
          .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    }
  }
}
```

With a simple `BackgroundView` and `SideBarView` as well those work as expected.

```
struct SideBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
}

struct BackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

This was suggested in the release notes and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57095524/5815048).

How can I avoid to hardcode those values as I could before by using `.relativeWidth(0.3)` instead of `.frame(idealWidth:)`?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Note: Using `.relativeWidth` never actually worked, e.g. using `0.3` as a relative value never resulted in a view that was 30 % of the width of the parent, but you could get close to your desired result through trial-and-error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it, one way is using `.overlay` instead of `ZStack`. The view you use in the overlay, will get the size of the `BackgroundView` offered by the parent. Then you simply use [GeometryReader](https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/) to get the width and multiply it by 0.7:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    BackgroundView().overlay(SideBarView())
  }
}

struct SideBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack {
                Spacer()

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.7)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Although I find it weird that it is so complicated for a relative common and simple feature.