# Proportional height (or width) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, autolayout

I started exploring SwiftUI and I can't find a way to get a simple thing: I'd like a View to have proportional height (basically a percentage of its parent's height). Let's say I have 3 views vertically stacked. I want:

- The first to be 43% (of its parent's height) high
- The second to be 37% (of its parent's height) high
- The last to be 20% (of its parent's height) high

I watched this interesting video from the WWDC19 about custom views in SwiftUI (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/) and I understood (correct me if I'm wrong) that basically a View never has a size per se, the size is the size of its children. So, the parent view asks its children how tall they are. They answer something like: "half your height!" and then... what? How does the layout system (that is different from the layout system we are used to) manage this situation?

If you write the below code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

The SwiftUI layout system sizes each view to be 1/3 high and this is right according to the video I posted here above.
You can wrap the rectangles in a frame this way:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 200)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: 400)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

This way the layout system sizes the first rectangle to be 200 high, the second one to be 400 high and the third one to fit all the left space. And again, this is fine.
What you can't do (this way) is specifying a proportional height.

Comment: You could use GeometryReader to get the size of the parent to calculate it by yourself.

Comment: According to the slides on the link, the parent can propose a size for the child. The child then manages itself and creates it size relation to that proposition. What results are you getting when you do the above?

Comment: @impression7vx Take a look at the EDIT.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

### UPDATE

If your deployment target at least iOS 16, macOS 13, tvOS 16, or watchOS 9, you can write a custom `Layout`. For example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyLayout: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        return proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions()
    }

    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        precondition(subviews.count == 3)

        var p = bounds.origin
        let h0 = bounds.size.height * 0.43
        subviews[0].place(
            at: p,
            proposal: .init(width: bounds.size.width, height: h0)
        )
        p.y += h0

        let h1 = bounds.size.height * 0.37
        subviews[1].place(
            at: p,
            proposal: .init(width: bounds.size.width, height: h1)
        )
        p.y += h1

        subviews[2].place(
            at: p,
            proposal: .init(
                width: bounds.size.width,
                height: bounds.size.height - h0 - h1
            )
        )
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(MyLayout {
    Color.pink
    Color.indigo
    Color.mint
}.frame(width: 50, height: 100).padding())
```

Result:

[image: a pink block 43 points tall atop an indigo block 37 points tall atop a mint block 20 points tall]

Although this is more code than the `GeometryReader` solution (below), it can be easier to debug and to extend to a more complex layout.

### ORIGINAL

You can make use of `GeometryReader`. Wrap the reader around all other views and use its closure value `metrics` to calculate the heights:

```
let propHeight = metrics.size.height * 0.43
```

Use it as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { metrics in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.red.frame(height: metrics.size.height * 0.43)
                Color.green.frame(height: metrics.size.height * 0.37)
                Color.yellow
            }
        }
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you get the chance can you slightly improve your answer? What I don't get here is why you have to specify that "layoutPriority(1)" modifier (I know what layoutPriority does, but I don't understand why it's needed here). Also, can you take a look at my EDIT and explain us why the "relativeHeight" modifier won't work here? Thank you again.

Comment: You have to specify `layoutPriority` because it doesn’t work otherwise. I don’t understand why it doesn’t work otherwise. It might be a SwiftUI bug. All I know is that, from experimentation, I found that using `layoutPriority` makes it work. As for `relativeHeight`, it is deprecated, so I’m not interested in investigating how to make it work.

Comment: Thx. I didn't know that relativeHeight was deprecated. For the layoutPriority issue I'll keep trying to find out what's happening.

Comment: It seems beta 5 fixed the .layoutPriority() problem and might not be needed anymore for this to work.

Comment: Just updated MacOS and xCode to Beta 5 and, as suggested by @kontiki, there's no need for the .layoutPriority() anymore. Rob, would you mind update your answer? Thank you guys.

Comment: relativeHeight and relativeWidth are completely disappeared :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of proportional width in SwiftUI

**Before iOS 16:**

```
struct GeometryReaderHStack: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      HStack(spacing: .zero) {
        let component1Width = geometry.size.width * 0.75
        let component2Width = geometry.size.width * 0.25
        Text("3/4")
          .frame(width: component1Width)
          .background(.red)

        Text("1/4")
          .frame(width: component2Width)
          .background(.blue)
      }
    }
    .frame(height: .zero)
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. you need to add `.frame(height: .zero)` to force the
   `GeometryReader` to respect its content size. if u don't add this,
   the GeometryReader will go edge to edge full screen of the device. U
   can add a `.background(.gray)` on GeometryReader scope to see the
   side effect!
2. if u need to add spacing for `HStack`, it doesn't work as expected. instead of deducting/excluding the spacing and then lay out the subviews, it will push other subviews out of screen! U may want to use `.padding` for each subview

**After iOS 16+:**

I can see `Layout` already mentioned by others but below is my spike. It is CustomHStack which works well with `spacing` however may need some extra work like (guarding around number of widthWeights must be the same as subviews counts, and `VerticalAlignment` implementation possibly)

```
struct CustomHStack: Layout {
  let widthWeights: [CGFloat]
  let spacing: CGFloat

  init(widthWeights: [CGFloat], spacing: CGFloat? = nil) {
    self.widthWeights = widthWeights
    self.spacing = spacing ?? .zero
  }

  func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
    let maxHeight = subviews
      .map { proxy in
        return proxy.sizeThatFits(.unspecified).height
      }
      .max() ?? .zero

    return CGSize(width: proposal.width ?? .zero, height: maxHeight)
  }

  func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
    let subviewSizes = subviews.map { proxy in
      return proxy.sizeThatFits(.infinity)
    }

    var x = bounds.minX
    let y = bounds.minY
    let parentTotalWith = (proposal.width ?? .zero) - (CGFloat((widthWeights.count - 1)) * spacing)

    for index in subviews.indices {
      let widthWeight = widthWeights[index]
      let proposedWidth = widthWeight * parentTotalWith

      let sizeProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: proposedWidth, height: subviewSizes[index].height)

      subviews[index]
        .place(
          at: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
          anchor: .topLeading,
          proposal: sizeProposal
        )

      x += (proposedWidth + spacing)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ProportionalWidthHStack: View {
  var body: some View {
    CustomHStack(widthWeights: [0.75, 0.25]) {
      Text("3/4")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.red)
      Text("1/4")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.blue)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy to do with a Grid too for horizontal proportions for folks that need that.

```
Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
    GridRow {
        ForEach(0 ..< 10) { _ in
            Color.clear
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 0)
    GridRow {
        Color.red
            .gridCellColumns(2) // 20 %
        Color.green
            .gridCellColumns(8) // 80 %
    }
}
```