# How to set height and width in proportion with superview in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I want to know that is it possible to adjust `height` and `width` in proportion according to superview in `SwiftUI` to any `UIControl` ?

As we are doing like :

```
let txtFld = UITextField()
txtFld.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/2, height: self.view.frame.height*0.1))
```

I know we can somehow achieve to adjust width by using `Spacer()`,  `.padding` and `edgeInsets`. But what about `height`? I have seen lots of tutorial for `SwiftUI`, everywhere `height` is static. Even on Apple's site. [SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views#compose-the-detail-view)

If anyone have knowledge about how to set height in proportion with view's height, please share here. Because at some point we need like that. For ex. If it needs to make button according to device height. (Let's say in iPhone SE = 40, iPhone 8P = 55, iPhone X = 65)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proportional height (or width) in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243677/proportional-height-or-width-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GeometryReader` to get that information from the parent:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
           /*
             Implement your view content here
             and you can use the geometry variable
             which contains geometry.size of the parent
             You also have function to get the bounds
             of the parent: geometry.frame(in: .global)
           */
        }
    }
}
```

You can have a custom struct for you `View` and bind it's geometry to a variable to make it's geometry accessible from out of the `View` itself.

### - Example:

First define a view called GeometryGetter (giving credit to @kontiki):

```swift
struct GeometryGetter: View {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect

    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.makeView(geometry: geometry)
        }
    }

    func makeView(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        }

        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Then, to get the bounds of a Text view (or any other view):

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var rect: CGRect = CGRect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("some text").background(GeometryGetter($rect))

        // You can then use rect in other places of your view:
        Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: rect.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: @VRAwesome I have added an example. Check that out.

Comment: This looked like a fantastic idea, however for me (Xcode 11.2.1) it crashes on `self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)` with error "precondition failure: invalid input index: 1"

Comment: I haven't update my Xcode yet, I will check the issue when I'm done and let you know. I hope you can do this yourself with the help of the idea till then. ;) @Grimxn