Custom HStack with Layout - What is the default spacing?
I try to create a custom HStack using Layout. I would like to have similar syntax like HStack and using the same spacing, if the user doesn't provide a custom spacing. But I cannot find out: What is the default spacing for HStackLayout?
I try to give some code or extra information:
This is the Apple definition:
@frozen public struct HStackLayout : Layout {

    /// The vertical alignment of subviews.
    public var alignment: VerticalAlignment

    /// The distance between adjacent subviews.
    ///
    /// Set this value to `nil` to use default distances between subviews.
    public var spacing: CGFloat?
...

I would like to know, what the use as the spacing, if you don't provide a custom value.

Yes, as I said, I try to create a custom HStack like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356936/2062613. Actually I would like to improve this solution also by using the default spacing.

I believe LayoutSubview.spacing is what you are looking for.

Thank you very much, that's it (just found out in that moment by myself, the Apple documentation is surprisingly good)

HStack's automatic spacing uses the views' own preferred spacings between other views. You can access this using the LayoutSubview.spacing property.
Example:
func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
    // suppose you want to find the default horizontal spacing between these two views:
    let view1 = subviews[0]
    let view2 = subviews[1]

    let spacing = view1.spacing.distance(to: view2.spacing, along: .horizontal)
}

Note that this spacing differs, depending on the types of the two views. Each kind of view has their own preferred spacing to other views.
