# Clip image to square in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to put multiple cells next to each other where each cell consists of an image and a text below. The cell itself should be a square and the image should be scaled to fill the remaining space (cutting a part of the image).

First I tried just making the image square and the text below.
Now my problem is, that I don't know how to properly achieve that in SwiftUI. I can get it to work, when using this code:

```swift
VStack {
    Image(uiImage: recipe.image!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        .clipped()
    Text(recipe.name)
}
```

[image: Image 1]
The problem is, that I have to specify a fixed frame size. What I want is a way to make a cell, that keeps an aspect ratio of 1:1 and is resizable, so I can fit a dynamic amount of them on a screen next to each other.

I also tried using

```
VStack {
    Image(uiImage: recipe.image!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
        .clipped()
    Text(recipe.name)
}
```

[image: Image 2]
which gives me square images, that scale dynamically. But the problem is, that the image now gets stretched to fill the square and not scaled to fill it.

My next idea was to clip it to a square shape. For that I first tried to clip it into a circle shape (because apparently there is not square shape):

```swift
VStack {
    Image(uiImage: recipe.image!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    Text(recipe.name)
}
```

[image: Image 3]

But for some odd reason, it didn't really clip the image but instead kept the remaining space...

So am I not seeing something or is the only option to clip an image square the frame modifier?

### EDIT

To clarify: I don't care about the text as much, as about the whole cell (or if it's simpler the image) being square, without having to specify its size via `.frame` and without the non-square original image being stretched to make it fit.

So the perfect solution would be that the VStack is square but getting a square image would also be okay. It should look like Image 1, but without having to use the `.frame` modifier.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A ZStack will help solve this by allowing us to layer views without one effecting the layout of the other.

For the text:

`.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)` to expand the text horizontally to its parent's size

`.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)` is useful in other situations

As for the image:

`.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` to make the image maintain its aspect ratio rather than squashing to the size of its frame.

`.layoutPriority(-1)` to de-prioritize laying out the image to prevent it from expanding its parent (the `ZStack` within the `ForEach` in our case).

The value for `layoutPriority` just needs to be lower than the parent views which will be set to 0 by default. We have to do this because SwiftUI will layout a child before its parent, and the parent has to deal with the child size unless we manually prioritize differently.

The [`.clipped()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle/3286668-clipped) modifier uses the bounding frame to mask the view so you'll need to set it to clip any images that aren't already 1:1 aspect ratio.

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { index in
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "doc.plaintext")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .layoutPriority(-1)
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("yes")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.white)
                    }
                }
                .clipped()
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .border(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: While geometry readers are super useful I think they should be avoided whenever possible. It's cleaner to let SwiftUI do the work. This is my initial solution with a [`Geometry Reader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729619/what-is-geometry-reader-in-swiftui) that works just as well.

```
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { index in
                ZStack {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("yes")
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                                .background(Color.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .clipped()
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .border(Color.red)
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Text isn't the problem. My main problem is to make the image square without having to specify its size manually (via `.frame`). If I find a solution to cut the image square with SwiftUI and then put a text under/on top of it, I'm fine with that. Also your solution still stretches the image. If you don't use "pencil", but an image, that is not square, it will stretch it to make it square, not cut it.

Comment: @iComputerfreak Updated my answer to better address your question.

Comment: I updated my question aswell. Your solution still requires me so specify the size of the ZStack via `.frame`, but I want a solution, so I can let SwiftUI scale the cells dynamically. E.g. by putting three cells next to each other in a HStack, so that they can fill the whole width of the screen. I will look into `GeometryReader`

Comment: @iComputerfreak please see my updated code example. I think that is what you're looking for, I'm not aware of a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! The GeometryReader solution was exactly what I was looking for. I had to move the `.clipped()` to the end of the `ZStack` though, otherwise the image would clip out of the cell.

Comment: Dope! Glad I was able to help. What order did you put the zStack modifiers in? I'll update my answer for others.

Comment: I put `clipped()` first, but it doesn't seem to matter. Also, if you add the `height: proxy.size.height` argument for the frame of the image, the image will get centered vertically.

Comment: Could reproduce the effect using both techniques.
Here is a runnable version (with cookie images!):
https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/blob/master/SwiftUIPlayground/Views/ClipImageSquareView.swift

Comment: layoutPriority(-1) did the trick. Thank you so much: you just saved me sooooooo much time and nerves.

Comment: setting layout priority did not work for me.

Answer (score 19):

Here's another solution I found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/mqe2vh/how_to_make_an_image_square/) and improved a bit:

```
Color.clear
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    .overlay(
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
        )
    .clipShape(Rectangle())
```

It is similar to Chads answer but differs in the way you put image relatively to the clear color (background vs overlay)

**Bonus:** to let it have circular shape just use `.clipShape(Circle())` as the last modifier. Everything else stays unchanged

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, but I don't know why cornerRadius is necessary...

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ClippedImage: View {
    let imageName: String
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    init(_ imageName: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
        }
        .cornerRadius(0) // Necessary for working
        .frame(width: width, height: height)
    }
}

struct ClippedImage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ClippedImage("dishLarge1", width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - .layoutPriority(-1) on an Image inside ZStack worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer that worked for me:

```
VStack {
  Color.clear
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    .background(Image(uiImage: recipe.image!)
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill))
    .clipped()
  Text(recipe.name)
}
```

I use clear color, then set the aspect ratio using fit.  That makes the container square.  Then I added a background of the image set it to fill.  To top it off, I add clipped so the background doesn't spill over the edges of the square.

Answer (score 3):

Answer based on the one by [@ramzesenok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444311/2762277) but wrapped into a view modifier

Modifier:

```swift
struct FitToAspectRatio: ViewModifier {

    let aspectRatio: Double
    let contentMode: SwiftUI.ContentMode

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Color.clear
            .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay(
                content.aspectRatio(nil, contentMode: contentMode)
            )
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
    }

}
```

You can optionally also add an extension function for easy access

```swift
extension Image {
    func fitToAspect(_ aspectRatio: Double, contentMode: SwiftUI.ContentMode) -> some View {
        self.resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .modifier(FitToAspectRatio(aspectRatio: aspectRatio, contentMode: contentMode))
    }
}
```

and then simply

```swift
Image(...).fitToAspect(1, contentMode: .fill)
```

Answer (score 0):

**GeometryReader for frame**

```
 var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
       ScrollView {
           VStack(spacing: 1) {
               ForEach(recipes) { recipe in
                   GalleryView(width: geometry.size.width, recipe: recipe)
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
     }
 }
```

**Overlapping gestures**

If you have gesture actions and images close each other, add  `.contentShape()` modifier to assign the tappable area.

*Width* and *height* get from GeometryReader of the previous View.

```
struct GalleryView: View {

    var width: CGFloat
    var recipe: Recipe

    private enum C {
        static let goldenRatio = CGFloat(0.67)
    }

    var body: some View {
       VStack(spacing: 1) {
          Image(uiImage: recipe.image)
              .resizable()
              .scaledToFill()
              .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .center)
              .clipped()
              .contentShape(Rectangle())

          Text(recipe.name)
        }
        .frame(height: width * C.goldenRatio + 1)
        .frame(width: width * C.goldenRatio / 2)
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
Image(uiImage: recipe.image)
   .resizable()
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
   .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
   .clipped()
```