# How do you clip an image to a square inside a lazy grid? (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swiftui

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290963/clip-image-to-square-in-swiftui).

Below you'll see a grid of rectangles with 3 columns. I'm trying to achieve the same effect but with images. The images should be clipped, but otherwise not appear stretched or distorted.

Here's how I achieved the rectangle grid...

```
// In my view struct...

private let threeColumnGrid = [
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
]

// In my body...

LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(model.imageNames, id: \.self) { imageName in
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

This is the layout I want using Rectangles...

[image]

This is my goal...

[image]

**Update:**

If I do this...

```
Image(item)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
```

The images distort if their aspect ratio wasn't already 1:1. For example, the circle image in the screenshot below should be a perfect circle.

[image]

Comment: Image has own size, but Shape, in this case Rectangle, does not, so layout might differ (with same input parameters). Would you show somehow what do you expect to get for images?

Comment: I've updated my question with an example of what I want.

Answer (score 19):

I found a solution.

Defining the number of columns...

```
// Somewhere in my view struct
private let threeColumnGrid = [
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
]
```

Creating the grid...

```
LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(model.imageNames, id: \.self) { item in
        GeometryReader { gr in
            Image(item)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(height: gr.size.width)
        }
        .clipped()
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved this same issue for me but with changing the frame modifier to .frame(height: gr.size.width) so that my image would always have the same width and height. I'm curious what setting the frame's width to the geometry's proposed width does here.

Comment: is it me or does this not center the image in the middle of the square though?

Comment: Try this frame modifier:frame(height: gr.size.width, alignment: .center)

Answer (score 13):

I found the DPMitu's answer was not centering the image (it was aligned to the leading edge).

This worked better for me (which also doesn't require GeometryReader):

```
  LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 30) {
       ForEach(items) { item in
           Image("IMG_0044")
               .resizable()
               .scaledToFill()
               .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
               .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
               .clipped() //Alternatively you can use cornerRadius for the same effect
               //.cornerRadius(10)
       }
  }
```

I found it here https://www.appcoda.com/learnswiftui/swiftui-gridlayout.html about half way down the page

Comment: This doesn't appear to achieve the square effect with portrait images...

Comment: To achieve the same with portrait images, change the .frame() line to .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).  It should work with both landscape and portrait this way, so long as the parent view's frame is square.

Comment: saved my day, thank you

Answer (score 8):

Some were asking about the image appearing off center. You can adjust that by adding in the line `.position(x: gr.frame(in: .local).midX, y: gr.frame(in: .local).midY)`. So the full thing would be:

Number of Columns

```
// Somewhere in my view struct
private let threeColumnGrid = [
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
]
```

Creating the Grid

```
LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(model.imageNames, id: \.self) { item in
        GeometryReader { gr in
            Image(item)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(height: gr.size.width)
                .position(x: gr.frame(in: .local).midX, y: gr.frame(in: .local).midY)
        }
        .clipped()
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Solution without `GeometryReader` and images that scale correctly.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    ]

    private let imageNames = ["image0", "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"];

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, content: {
            ForEach(imageNames, id: \.self) { name in
                Color.clear
                    .background(Image(name)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                    )
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipped()
                    .contentShape(Rectangle()) // <-- this is important to fix gesture recognition
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is very close to the easiest solution! This doesn't use `GeometryReader` or frame:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(model.imageNames, id: \.self) { imageName in
          Rectangle()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
            .overlay {
              Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            }
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .clipped()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and this is how I solved it.

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    Image(item)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .clipShape(
            Rectangle()
                .size(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width)
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement using Rectangle for help, just below

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 88, maximum: 128), spacing: 2)], spacing: 2) {
    ForEach(urls, id: \.self) { url in
        Rectangle()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.relativePath) {
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

**1. By using GeometryReader**

```swift
    var gridView: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 2, alignment: nil),
                            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 2, alignment: nil),
                            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 2, alignment: nil)],
                  alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
            
            ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0 , contentMode: .fill)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .overlay {
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Image("iphone")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.width, alignment: .center)
                                .clipped()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

**2. By setting frames:**

```swift
    var gridView: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 2, alignment: nil),
                            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 2, alignment: nil),
                            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 2, alignment: nil)],
                  alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
            
            ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0 , contentMode: .fill)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .overlay {
                        Image("iphone")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                            .clipped()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm suggesting not using **GeometryReader** it has some overload. Especially when loading a long list. It has to calculate each item's size.