# Uniform size of images inside a LazyVGrid

Tags: ios, image, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I'm working with a `LazyVGrid` with `SwiftUI` to **display 8 images**.

As you can see from the photo, the dimensions of the images are not uniform, some are exact, others have a lower height than the next photo ..

[image]

I don't understand why this happens .. Do you have any ideas to solve the problem?

This is how I created the `LazyVGrid`

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160), spacing: 10)], spacing: 20) {
                
       ForEach(productsItems) { product in
           VStack {
              Image(product.image)
              .resizable()
              .scaledToFill()
              .cornerRadius(5)
              .padding(5)
              .background(
                   RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                   .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 0.5)
              )
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the images have different aspect ratios, so if they scale to the same width the height is different.
If you want all images cropped in the same aspect ratio, you can follow this approach:
[Clip image to square in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290963/clip-image-to-square-in-swiftui)