# SwiftUI ScrollView with content frame update closure

Tags: ios, macos, scrollview, swiftui, contentoffset

I want to have a `ScrollView` where you can be aware of the content frame changes as the user scrolls (similar to `didScroll` delegate in UIKit `UIScrollView`).

With this, you can then perform layout changes based on the scroll behavior.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to come with a nice solution for this problem by making use of **View Preferences** as a method to notify layout information upstream in the View Hierarchy.

For a very detail explanation of how **View Preferences** work, I will suggest reading this [3 articles series](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/) on the topic by [kontiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7786555/kontiki)

For my solution, I implemented two `ViewModifiers`: one to make a view report changes on its layout using **anchor preferences**, and the second to allow a `View` to handle updates to frames on views on its subtree.

To do this, we first define a `Struct` to carry the identifiable frame information upstream:

```swift
/// Represents the `frame` of an identifiable view as an `Anchor`
struct ViewFrame: Equatable {

    /// A given identifier for the View to faciliate processing
    /// of frame updates
    let viewId : String


    /// An `Anchor` representation of the View
    let frameAnchor: Anchor<CGRect>

    // Conformace to Equatable is required for supporting
    // view udpates via `PreferenceKey`
    static func == (lhs: ViewFrame, rhs: ViewFrame) -> Bool {
        // Since we can currently not compare `Anchor<CGRect>` values
        // without a Geometry reader, we return here `false` so that on
        // every change on bounds an update is issued.
        return false
    }
}
```

and we define a `Struct` conforming to `PreferenceKey` protocol to hold the view tree preference changes:

```swift
/// A `PreferenceKey` to provide View frame updates in a View tree
struct FramePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [ViewFrame] // The list of view frame changes in a View tree.

    static var defaultValue: [ViewFrame] = []

    /// When traversing the view tree, Swift UI will use this function to collect all view frame changes.
    static func reduce(value: inout [ViewFrame], nextValue: () -> [ViewFrame]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
```

Now we can define the `ViewModifiers` I mentioned:

**Make a view report changes on its layout**:

This just adds a `transformAnchorPreference` modifier to the View with a handler that simply constructs a `ViewFrame` instance with current frame `Anchor` value and appends it to the current value of the `FramePreferenceKey`:

```swift
/// Adds an Anchor preference to notify of frame changes
struct ProvideFrameChanges: ViewModifier {
    var viewId : String

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .transformAnchorPreference(key: FramePreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds) {
                $0.append(ViewFrame(viewId: self.viewId, frameAnchor: $1))
            }
    }
}

extension View {

    /// Adds an Anchor preference to notify of frame changes
    /// - Parameter viewId: A `String` identifying the View
    func provideFrameChanges(viewId : String) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: ProvideFrameChanges(viewId: viewId))
    }
}
```

**Provide an update handler to a view for frame changes on its subtree:**

This adds a `onPreferenceChange` modifier to the View, where the list of frame Anchors changes are transformed into frames(`CGRect`) on the view's coordinate space and reported as a dictionary of frame updates keyed by the view ids:

```swift
typealias ViewTreeFrameChanges = [String : CGRect]

/// Provides a block to handle internal View tree frame changes
/// for views using the `ProvideFrameChanges` in own coordinate space.
struct HandleViewTreeFrameChanges: ViewModifier {
    /// The handler to process Frame changes on this views subtree.
    /// `ViewTreeFrameChanges` is a dictionary where keys are string view ids
    /// and values are the updated view frame (`CGRect`)
    var handler : (ViewTreeFrameChanges)->Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { contentGeometry in
            content
                .onPreferenceChange(FramePreferenceKey.self) {
                    self._updateViewTreeLayoutChanges($0, in: contentGeometry)
                }
        }
    }

    private func _updateViewTreeLayoutChanges(_ changes : [ViewFrame], in geometry : GeometryProxy) {
        let pairs = changes.map({ ($0.viewId, geometry[$0.frameAnchor]) })
        handler(Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: pairs))
    }
}

extension View {
    /// Adds an Anchor preference to notify of frame changes
    /// - Parameter viewId: A `String` identifying the View
    func handleViewTreeFrameChanges(_ handler : @escaping (ViewTreeFrameChanges)->Void) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: HandleViewTreeFrameChanges(handler: handler))
    }
}
```

**LET'S USE IT:**

I will illustrate the usage with an example:

Here I will get notifications of a *Header View* frame changes inside a `ScrollView`. Since this *Header View* is on the top of the `ScrollView` content, the reported frame changes on the frame origin are equivalent to the `contentOffset` changes of the `ScrollView`

```swift
enum TestEnum : String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten

    var id: String {
        rawValue
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    private let _listHeaderViewId = "testView_ListHeader"

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // Header View
            Text("This is some Header")
                .provideFrameChanges(viewId: self._listHeaderViewId)

            // List of test values
            ForEach(TestEnum.allCases) {
                Text($0.rawValue)
                    .padding(60)
            }
        }
            .handleViewTreeFrameChanges {
                self._updateViewTreeLayoutChanges($0)
            }
    }

    private func _updateViewTreeLayoutChanges(_ changes : ViewTreeFrameChanges) {
        print(changes)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's great. 
I have a question: if  multiple views have `provideFrameChanges`,  how `handleViewTreeFrameChanges` callback could identify change sources?

Comment: @LiangWang, sorry for late answer. Basically the `ViewFrame` Struct that is passed in the callback has a `viewId` which is a `String` you can set to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant solution to this problem, Soroush Khanlou already posted a Gist of it so I won't copy-paste it. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/khanlou/112cbb13ee2c776aa343bfc204f78259) and yeah...Shame that it isn't a part of the framework yet!